# How to find Child Element in a Parent WebElement in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I thought `WebElement.findElement()` only searched the DOM below the element,
but it apparently searches the whole DOM. I have something like this in HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <td>Some Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="network">
      <td><input ...></td>
  <tr>
      <td>Some More Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="network">
       <td><input ...></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And selenium code as below:

```
    List<WebElement> tableRows =
    radioTable.findElements(By.CssSelector("tbody > tr"));
    for (WebElement row : tableRows) {
    String s = row.getAttribute("class");
    if (s.equals("network")) {

    currentGroup.add(row.findElement(By.CssSelector(".network")));
    }
```

However the `row.findElement()` call searches from the top of the DOM and
finds the same initial  each time.

It would be very useful if `WebElement.findElement()` just searched under the
current element.

Comment: It is searching only child nodes of that element. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: I'm not sure why it does not search under current node but if you need like to search under row element try using `xpath` as `row.findElement(By.CssSelector(".//*[@class = 'network']"))` here `.` will denotes to row as current node..:)

Comment: Thanks , It works in XPATH like u suggested, But i need something equivalent that works in CssSelector. , Is there anything that denotes as current row?? Am using a framework that supports only CssSelector. cant use XPath

Answer (score 0):

Well we can get the index of row element and using nth-child selector we could then select the child element as so.

```js
List <WebElement> tableRows =
radioTable.findElements(By.CssSelector("tbody > tr"));
tableRows.forEach((row, index) => {
    String s = row.getAttribute("class");
    if (s.equals("network")) {
        currentGroup.add(row.findElement(By.CssSelector(`.network:nth-child(${index + 1}) .network`)));
    }
})
```